# Is there a more elegant way to iterate over json array in js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, iteration

I am trying to iterate over a json array and calculate number of hours from every object. The code works but it just feels like there could be a more efficient way to write the code, but whatever I try the code just breaks.

My json array:

```
{
    "timesheetItems":[
        {
        "id":"1",
        "title":"Ticket system integration",
        "hours":2
        },
        {
        "id":"2",
        "title":"Integration with Google Maps API",
        "hours":3
        },
        {
        "id":"3",
        "title":"Prepare test cases",
        "hours":4
        }
    ]
}
```

Iteration:

```
let numberOfSheets = 0;
const lam = this.state.sheets.forEach( item => numberOfSheets += item.hours)
```

Comment: Try `this.state.sheets.reduce((total, { hours }) => total + hours, 0)`

Answer (score 1):

Try using `reduce` on the `timesheetItems` array:

```js
var sheets = {
    "timesheetItems":[
        {
        "id":"1",
        "title":"Ticket system integration",
        "hours":2
        },
        {
        "id":"2",
        "title":"Integration with Google Maps API",
        "hours":3
        },
        {
        "id":"3",
        "title":"Prepare test cases",
        "hours":4
        }
    ]
}

let numberOfSheets = sheets.timesheetItems.reduce((numberOfSheets, item) => numberOfSheets + item.hours, 0);

console.log(numberOfSheets);
```

Comment: Remember that the above is an example only. You need to adapt it to your own  code (e.g. by replacing `sheets` with `this.state.sheets`).